# Maximum subarray_problem understanding

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am researching the maximum subarray problem. It would appear that I haven't gotten the core idea. Let's say you have the following array: `int arr[] ={10, 4, 2, 12, 16, 1}` From what I understand the maximum subarray should be equal to 14, since the lowest and highest possible sub array is 2 (the third element) and 16 (the 5th element) right? Well, apperantly not. I implemented the linear time algorithm which I found here: http://heliang.me/wiki/index.php?title=4.1_The_maximum-subarray_problem 
It's implementation in c++"

```
int max_sarr(int arr[], int size)
{
    int  max_sum = -9999;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        if(sum > max_sum)
            max_sum = sum;
        if(sum < 0)
            sum = 0;
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 4, 2, 12, 16, 1};
    int p = max_sarr(arr, 6);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 45. So... where is the mistake in my thought process ?

Comment: The maximal subarray is just a subarray with the max possible sum, simple as that.

Comment: Your understanding is most wrong and bizarre. The algorithm is correct. It is hard to find your error because you have not demonstrated any thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the problem. The problem is to find the contiguous subarray of the given array such that it has the highest sum of all subarrays. That is, it basically finds a first element and last element within the array which, if you summed up the elements including and between them, would give you the maximum possible value.

If all of the values in your array are positive, then the maximum subarray is always the entire array. In this case, if you add up all the elements in the array, you get 45.

Consider an array with values `{-5, 10, -3, 22}`. We can enumerate all of the subarrays of this:

```
Subarrays of length 0: {}
Subarrays of length 1: {-5}             {10}         {-3}     {22}
Subarrays of length 2: {-5, 10}         {10, -3}     {-3, 22}
Subarrays of length 3: {-5, 10, -3}     {10, -3, 22}
Subarrays of length 4: {-5, 10, -3, 22}
```

The subarray with the maximum sum is `{10 -3 22}`, whose sum is 29.

Answer (score 2):

sftrabbit's answer is great, however I strongly recommend the *The Maximum Subarray Problem* section in [CLRS book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) page 68. It is very clear and it also discusses the asymptotic complexity and the real life occurences of the problem.

In addition to this, as you might expect, an array with all positive elements, the maximum subarray of it will be the array itself.